# Assignment of several statements enclosed in parentheses and curly braces in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I was perusing the code of the third-party `RESideMenu` framework, and noticed some strange syntax that seemed to work just fine. Here is the confusing bit:

```
self.tableView = ({
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.autoresizingMask = mask;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.opaque = NO;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    tableView.bounces = NO;
    tableView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    tableView;
});
```

How does this syntax work? I suspect it has something to do with a C-level block scoping, but I have never seen this before. I also considered it may be a new feature with Objc-2.0 literals, but I don't think that is true.

So I guess my question is how does this work/what makes this work?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs

Comment: BTW I had the same question; you might like to look at this thread: http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2013/Aug/msg00027.html

Comment: In the end I decided not to use it in my own code. But note that you can get a similar effect with curly braces alone, if all you want to do is confine the scope of a temporary variable declaration.

Comment: Interesting to know, thanks for the information! I have been searching for quite some time - I like that it logically separates the initialization code, makes it look cleaner in my opinion :)

Comment: One more consideration: I don't trust these GCC extensions. I relied on this one for years: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions Then Apple withdrew it and all my code broke. So I said Never Again!

Comment: Good point. I suppose it's better to future-proof the code at the cost of syntactic sugar at that point. Thanks for all the insight!

Comment: @bgoers - To see this feature in use look at the standard macro `MAX` (& friends) in Xcode (and probably other compilers). It's a good way to make macros behave the same as functions - only evaluate their arguments once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/new-years-2014/):

> Behind the magic is a GCC C extension, which causes a code block to return a value if enclosed within brackets and parentheses.
>
> This not only segregates configuration details into initialization, but the additional scope allows generic variable names like frame, button, and view to be reused in subsequent initializations. No more loginButtonFrame = ... / signupButtonFrame = ...!

Comment: Thanks  for your answer!  @Gavin