# Can someone explain this objective-c syntax?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I haven't seen syntax like this before. Can someone explain whats happening here

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:150/255.0f green:161/255.0f blue:177/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.opaque = NO;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = ({
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 60.0f)];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 100, 100)];
        imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"];
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
        imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
        imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 0, 24)];
        label.text = @"Darren";
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:21];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [label sizeToFit];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

        //[view addSubview:imageView];
        [view addSubview:label];
        view;
    });
}
```

What is happening here when the tableHeaderView is assigned? What is the purpose of the view being created and configured within the ({ }) brackets? and how does it know to assign the created view to the tableHeaderView property?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's just Objective-C, showing off.

Comment: an anonymous function, wich returns `view` (the last line)

Comment: It's a C extension. See this: http://nshipster.com/new-years-2014/

Comment: `({})` is mainly used for macros e.g. `#define MAX(a,b) ({__typeof(a) __a = (a); __typeof(b) __b = (b); __a>__b?__a:__b; })`

Comment: Also [Assignment of several statements enclosed in parentheses and curly braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023070/assignment-of-several-statements-enclosed-in-parentheses-and-curly-braces-in-obj)

Comment: @DarrenFindlay - I mean that Objective-C syntax is often inexplicable, and proud of it!